# wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda4

Tags: partitioning, mount

I am trying to access a Windows filesystem from a former employee of ours who recently left without providing the password to their account. I booted the computer to Linux and am currently trying to mount it to Linux.

I start by doing the following:

```
sudo mkdir /media/windows
sudo mount /dev/sda4 /media/windows
```

Then receive the following error:

```
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda4,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error

       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail or so.
```

I have checked my packages regarding ntfs and receive the following after checking `dpkg -l | grep ntfs | grep ii`:

```
ii  ntfs-3g                                    1:2015.3.14AR.1-1ubuntu0.1                   amd64        read/write NTFS driver for FUSE
```

When I run `sudo fdisk -l` (shortened):

```
Disk /dev/sda: 238.5 GiB, 256060514304 bytes, 500118192 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: A4630A7F-007F-4A1E-B07F-E2E0498BB2EF

Device       Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1     2048   1023999   1021952   499M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda2  1024000   1228799    204800   100M EFI System
/dev/sda3  1228800   1261567     32768    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda4  1261568 500117503 498855936 237.9G Microsoft basic data
```

and `sudo parted -l`:

```
Model: ATA SanDisk SD7TB6S2 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 256GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End    Size    File system  Name                          Flags
 1      1049kB  524MB  523MB   ntfs         Basic data partition          hidden, diag
 2      524MB   629MB  105MB   fat32        EFI system partition          boot, esp
 3      629MB   646MB  16.8MB               Microsoft reserved partition  msftres
 4      646MB   256GB  255GB                Basic data partition          msftdata


Warning: The driver descriptor says the physical block size is 2048 bytes, but
Linux says it is 512 bytes.
```

Not sure what is left to do, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you know if it was encrypted?

Comment: Open the `Files` (Navigator) application, and just click on "Windows" (or similar) in the left pane. That will mount it for you, assuming it's not encrypted.

Comment: @colbycdev - not encrypted

Comment: @heynnema - there is no "Windows" or similar.

Comment: Show me a screenshot of an open `Files` window and I'll see if I can identify it for you.